# error in gitlab yaml - include and extends

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm having a gitlab yaml file whose before_scripts section needs to be used in another gitlab yaml. I'm doing something like this:

```
include:
  - remote: 'https://gitlab.xxx.net/awsxxx/job-template/-/blob/master/.gitlab- 
  ci-template.yml'
extends: 
  - before_script
```

The relevant contents of the above url file are:

```
before_script:
  - echo "foo"
  - echo "bar"
```

This is not working, returns that the syntax is incorrect. Can you please help me correct this? Note: There are multiple extends and multiple parent 'include' and so I'm using the '-' format for extends and include here

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error you're getting is because you can only use the `extends` keyword on a job, see the relavant page https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends. Are you trying to somehow append the remote yaml with your own `before_script` ? You should be able to reuse the job name from the remote yaml and do the before script there like:

```
include:
  - remote: 'https://gitlab.xxx.net/awsxxx/job-template/-/blob/master/.gitlab- 
  ci-template.yml'

job to overwrite from ci-template:
  before_script: 
   - echo "foo"
   - echo "bar"
```